# Load testing with Task.Run() inside a loop vs WhenAll()

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I wanted to do some simple load test on a piece of code I wrote with multiple threads hitting a piece of code at once.

Now the below code Sample #1 gave me the expected results. But I am not quite sure why Sample #2 didn't give me the same. Could someone explain, please?

**Code sample #1**

```
    private static FileCreator _fileCreater;
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        _fileCreater = new FileCreator();
        RunTasks().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    private static async Task RunTasks()
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                _fileCreater.SaveMessage(new Message());
            }));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
```

Initially, I had the below and I expected the same result, but what I noticed was my CPU never went past 20%, which suggested it wasn't really spanning up multiple threads

**Code Sample #2**

```
    private static FileCreator _fileCreater;
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        _fileCreater =  new FileCreator();
        RunTasks().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    private static async Task RunTasks()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                _fileCreater.SaveMessage(new Message());
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second piece of code is awaiting each task... so no they will not be run concurrently, as you wait for each to finish before starting the next.

Comment: I see, so you wait for each task to finish before executing the next one. What happens if you don't await a Task.Run() ?

Comment: Its... a bit complicated for a comment... execution of the original method will continue, depending on your scheduling context and available resources, the task may run on another thread and the original code will keep running on a different one. Why don't you take a look at the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming

Comment: Note that in your first example you are firing all the tasks, then awaiting them all finishing after they are all started. If you didn't await the Task.Run in your second example, it would be more similar to that behavior (although you don't wait for them to finish at all in that case)